# Is there a np.ix_ like function in SymPy?

Tags: sympy

I need to translate the following MATLAB code to SymPy, but, I cannot find an easy and straightforward answer:

```matlab
syms E A L P

long = [L;  L/2;  L/3];

LaG = [1 3
       2 3
       3 4];

k = E.*A./long;

K = sym(zeros(4));
for e = 1:3       
   idx = LaG(e,:);
   K(idx,idx) = K(idx,idx) + k(e)*[1 -1; -1 1]; 
end;
```

However, I cannot find in SymPy a command like NumPy's `np.ix_()`. Without this, my code will look too much complicated, and I will have to resort to MATLAB's symbolic toolbox for my entire course, since many of my codes rely on that `ix_()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is not an `sympy.ix_()` (or equivalent) function, I was able to solve my problem using the following code:

```py
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp

def ensamblar(K, idx, Ke):
    ''' Ensambla la matriz de rigidez local Ke en la matriz de rigidez global K

    Uso:
    ensamblar(K, idx, Ke)

    Parametros de entrada:
    K   -> matriz de rigidez global
    idx -> grados de libertad donde debe proceder el ensamblaje
    Ke  -> matriz de rigidez local
    '''

    # se verifican las dimensiones de las matrices
    nfil, ncol = K.shape
    assert nfil == ncol, "La matriz de rigidez K debe ser cuadrada"

    nfil, ncol = Ke.shape
    assert nfil == ncol == len(idx),\
            "Ke debe ser cuadrada y debe tener el mismo número de filas que idx"

    # se procede con el ensamblaje
    for i in range(nfil):
        for j in range(ncol):
            K[idx[i], idx[j]] += Ke[i,j]

# %% defino las variables
E, A, L, P = sp.symbols('E A L P')         # define las variables simbolicas

long = [L,  L,  L/2]                       # longitud de la barra

# LaG: local a global: matriz que relaciona nodos locales y globales
# (se lee la barra x va del nodo i al nodo j)
LaG = np.array([[1, 3],         # fila = barra
                [2, 3],         # col1 = nodo global asociado a nodo local 1
                [3, 4]]) - 1    # col2 = nodo global asociado a nodo local 2

k = [E*A/longitud for longitud in long]    # (k minuscula) rigidez de cada barra

# %% ensamblo la matriz de rigidez global (K mayuscula)
K = sp.zeros(4)       # separa memoria para matriz de rigidez global K
for e in range(3):    # para cada una de las barras e = 1, 2 y 3
   idx = LaG[e,:]     # extrae indices de los nodos globales de la barra e
   Ke  = k[e]*np.array([[1, -1],[-1, 1]])  # matriz de rigidez local
   ensamblar(K, idx, Ke)                   # ensamblaje matricial
```

Answer (score 1):

Although you do not show the use of `ix_` in your example, the [np doc page](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html) suggests that the SymPy `extract` method for matrices should do this:

```
    >>> m
    Matrix([
    [0,  1,  2],
    [3,  4,  5],
    [6,  7,  8],
    [9, 10, 11]])
    >>> e = [0, 1, 3], [0, 1]
    >>> m.extract(*e)
    Matrix([
    [0,  1],
    [3,  4],
    [9, 10]])
```

If you want to put the results into a contiguous subregion of a matrix then you can do

```
>>> m[:2, :2] = eye(2)
```

I am not aware of a method to put another matrix into a non-contiguous region but it is possible to define such a routine:

```
>>> m = Matrix(4,3,range(12))
>>> def assign(self, m, a, b):
...   assert len(a)*len(b) == len(m)
...   k = 0
...   for i in a:
...     for j in b:
...       self[i, j] = m[k]
...       k += 1
...
>>> n=eye(4)
>>> assign(n, m.extract(*e), *e); n
Matrix([
[0,  1, 0, 0],
[3,  4, 0, 0],
[0,  0, 1, 0],
[9, 10, 0, 1]])
```

Comment: Thanks! However, the method `extract()` does not allow assignment.  You cannot do
`m.extract([3, 1], [0, 1]) = m22` where `m22` is an 2x2 matrix. When I try to do this, I get the error `SyntaxError: can't assign to function call`

Comment: `m22=m.extract...` will store the result as a 2x2. Did you accidently reverse the order?

Comment: No, I did not. Observe that in the line 
`K(idx,idx) = K(idx,idx) + k(e)*[1 -1; -1 1];`
I am writing in the left hand side the "extracted matrix" so that I can assign to it the 2x2 matrix that appears in the right hand side. 

If I were using NumPy, I would write something like: 
`K[np.ix_(idx,idx)] += k[e]*np.array([[1,-1],[-1,1]])`. 
I am looking for the equivalent of that command in SymPy.

Comment: Your code did not work. You forgot to specify the variable `e`. However, thank you very much!!! You gave me a clue on how to solve my problem. Thank you again!!!